# Java 15 ModuleFinder encounters Error reading module

Tags: java, junit, java-module, java-platform-module-system, java-15

I am trying to programmatically load a project that is using Java Platform Module System, so I can analyze how many modules exist and what are the relationships. I wrote the following code:

```
public void retrieveModules() throws IOException {
    moduleRefs = new ArrayList<ModuleReference>();

    // search for all module-info.class
    Stream<Path> classPaths = Files.walk(Paths.get(this.basePath));
    List<String> moduleInfoClassFiles = classPaths
            .filter(p -> p.getFileName()
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains("module-info.class"))
            .map(p -> p.toString())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // load modules
    for (String classFilePath : moduleInfoClassFiles) {
        Path dir = Paths.get(classFilePath.replace("/module-info.class", ""));
        ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(dir);
        moduleRefs.addAll(finder.findAll());
    }
}
```

This code has been working fine as `finder.findAll()` finds the module and I can retrieve the correct module descriptor. However, when I am trying to run this on JUnit 5 (https://github.com/junit-team/junit5)

I got the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: /.../junit-team_junit5/junit-platform-engine/build/classes/java/module/org.junit.platform.commons
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readModule(ModulePath.java:350)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scan(ModulePath.java:237)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scanNextEntry(ModulePath.java:190)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.findAll(ModulePath.java:166)
    at RepoAnalyzer.retrieveModules(RepoAnalyzer.java:41)
    at RepoAnalyzer.main(RepoAnalyzer.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package org.junit.platform.commons.util not found in module
```

I tried to find out what went wrong. I verified that packages are correctly exported and required for both modules. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `ModuleFinder.of(dir)` knows where to read a module, but doesn’t account for any of that module’s possible dependencies, which reside in other directories.

Comment: Why do you use `.toLowerCase() .contains("module-info.class")`? The module-info’s name must be an *exact* match, not a case insensitive substring search. Even your own subsequent `replace("/module-info.class", "")` requires an exact match. So just use a straight-forward `equals("module-info.class")` and speaking of straight-forward, just call `getParent()` on the `Path` to get the parent `Path`, instead of converting it to a `String` to perform a string replacement operation and pass it to `Paths.get(…)` to get back a `Path`. Without the `List<String>` detour, this can be a single operation.

Comment: “I verified that packages are correctly exported…” yes, they are exported, but not found, which means there is no corresponding directory relative to the `module-info.class`’s location containing at least a single resource or class file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Holger! Why is the corresponding directory relative to the module-info.class not existing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to perform string manipulations with the paths you encountered. Your code can be simplified to

```java
public void retrieveModules() throws IOException {
    // search for all module-info.class
    try(Stream<Path> classPaths = Files.walk(Paths.get(this.basePath))) {
        moduleRefs = ModuleFinder.of(classPaths
            .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().equals("module-info.class"))
            .map(Path::getParent)
            .toArray(Path[]::new)).findAll();
    }
}
```

assuming that you can change `moduleRefs` to `Set` or `Collection` rather than `List`. Otherwise, wrap the expression in a `new ArrayList<>(…)`.

It seems that you are scanning an “exploded module” on the default filesystem and the encountered `module-info.class` has not an explicit declaration of all packages. What happens inside the `ModuleFinder` is equivalent to a call to [`ModuleDescriptor.read(InputStream in, Supplier<Set<String>> packageFinder)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.html#read(java.io.InputStream,java.util.function.Supplier)) whereas the supplied package finder will scan the subtree of the directory containing the module-info for directories containing at least one regular file, a class or resource, and having a name that forms a valid package name. All of them are considered packages of the module.

The documentation of the method states:

> ##### Throws
>
> InvalidModuleDescriptorException - If an invalid module descriptor is detected or the set of packages returned by the packageFinder does not include all of the packages obtained from the module descriptor

The packages obtained from the module descriptor are named in the [`packages()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.html#packages()):

> The set of packages includes all exported and open packages, as well as the packages of any service providers, and the package for the main class.

So the package `org.junit.platform.commons.util` has been identified as mandatory through the `module-info` but not found through the package finder, i.e. the corresponding directory might not exist.

You may try to narrow the problem by retracing these steps manually:

```java
public void checkModules() throws IOException {
    try(Stream<Path> classPaths = Files.walk(Paths.get(this.basePath))) {
        classPaths
            .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().equals("module-info.class"))
            .forEach(this::check);
    }
}
private void check(Path path) {
    try {
        ModuleDescriptor md = md(path);
        System.out.println("module " + md.name());

        for(String pkg: md.packages()) {
            Path pLoc = path.getParent();
            for(String sub: pkg.split("\\.")) pLoc = pLoc.resolve(sub);
            System.out.print("package " + pkg + ": " + pLoc);
            if(!Files.exists(pLoc)) System.out.println(" does not exist");
            else if(!Files.isDirectory(pLoc)) System.out.println(" is not a directory");
            else if(!checkClassOrResource(pLoc))
                System.out.println(" contains no class or resource");
            else System.out.println(" seems ok");
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
    }
}
private boolean checkClassOrResource(Path pLoc) throws IOException {
    try(Stream<Path> members = Files.list(pLoc)) {
        return members.anyMatch(Files::isRegularFile);
    }
}
private ModuleDescriptor md(Path p) throws IOException {
    try(InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(p)) {
        return ModuleDescriptor.read(is);
    }
}
```

This will check for the directories corresponding to the packages and print a diagnostic message. Note that the method `ModuleDescriptor.read(InputStream is)` variant without a package finder used above does not verify the package locations but uses only those found in the `module-info` which does already include all packages relevant for cross-module relationships. If you are not interested in the other packages in your analysis, you could simply use that method to construct a `ModuleDescriptor` for each `module-info` and proceed with them.

```java
try(Stream<Path> classPaths = Files.walk(Paths.get(this.basePath))) {
    List<ModuleDescriptor> modules = classPaths
        .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().equals("module-info.class"))
        .map(path -> {
            try(InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path)) {
                return ModuleDescriptor.read(is);
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
            }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it is great! I am really just looking for cross-module relationships and using just the ModuleDescriptor.read is sufficient. It is unclear to me why packages are not found in the modules. Do you have an idea why that is the case?

Comment: Did you try the second code snippet? It’s precisely for analyzing the potential problems with the packages.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I tried the second code snippet. It works great and is sufficient for what I am doing. I am still curious about why "packageFinder does not include all of the packages obtained from the module descriptor". I do not know if it is because I compiled the project wrong

Comment: What does it mean, “It works great”? The second code snippet performs an analysis, precisely to give the answer. If you ran it, what did it print?